# Change order of frames in unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

How do I change the order of the frames being played in an animation without screwing the animation up. I tried changing the name of the files but that did not work. Any ideas?

this is the order I have right now:

[image]

Comment: Can't you just re-import them? or  maybe you can change the order in the animation view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply by creating new `Animation Clip` or Edit available clip .

If you go `Animation` tab  you can drag new frame from your sprite that have animation parts .

Or you can move and delete each frame by clip .

[image]